# SQL: select * from multiple tables where the name ends with '_reports'

Tags: mysql

So i was working on an site where people could place text and images in a certain channel, and to prevent unwanted posts, i created a report button. When pressed there will be an new row inserted in the `*random_code*_reports`table, and the admins of that channel could react to them.

Howerver, also the site owners should be able to react on them, however i coudnt make an working query that select ALL the reports of all the *random_code*_reports tables that are out there

So, to be clear, when a channel is created, a few tables will be created:

`$code."_posts"`

`$code."_files"`

`$code."_comments"`

`$code."_likes"`

`$code."_reports"`

where code is an random value of 6 characters.

Is there some sort of like function for selecting certain tables with '_reports' in their name?

Comment: why have you got lots of separate tables for these different codes? Have they got different sets of fields in them or something? Surely you can just have one table for each thing (posts, comments, files etc) and have a Channel ID field which identifies the channel each row belongs to? I feel like there's some de-normalisation going on here which is then resulting in the problem stated in the question.

Comment: Using metadata to separate one table into multiple tables is a anti-SQL pattern... you should make one table report with a post_type_id column and a table (post_type) where you descripe the types   .. if you fear the table becomes to large you can use MySQL's (range) partitioning on the post_type_id colum but MySQL should be able to handle millions off records just fine when indexed.

Comment: In SQL, we don't query tables based on some dynamic-string for table name. That's why we have the whole data model based on table data-structure. Basically, you've done it wrong. Entirely. That's the completely wrong way to use SQL. However, now you're aware of it and luckily - you can change from wrong to right way.

Comment: So, just te be sure, what you guys are all saying,  is just dont create a separate table for each channel's post, reactions, likes ect ect,
 just create one for all, and insert an channel_id or channel_code with it, so you can select them later on.

This is exactly what i'm going to do right now, thank you for your anwsers!

Comment: @ward yes that's exactly what we're saying. Then your database is correctly "normalised". If you haven't come across this concept, it's a vital thing to understand when creating relational databases, so I recommend that you study it. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no SQL standard for selecting `FROM %_table`

See: [possible to create sql query with table wildcards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408186/possible-to-create-sql-query-with-table-wildcards)

You must simply select all tables first by querying some sort of meta information.

`SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%_reports';`

(note, this is mysql specific, other DB servers have other ways of querying the available tables)

You could reorganize your data into multiple databases instead of table prefixes and then query with

`SELECT * FROM $random_code.reports`

In this way, you could move entire databases with large amounts of data to their own servers and adjust your connection string to find which channels are associated with which servers (called single tenant databases)

Or, you could add the random code as a column, sometimes called a descriminator column or multi-tenant databases.

`SELECT * FROM reports where channel_code = '$random_code'`

`SELECT count(*) FROM reports group by channel_code`